# Android volley POST request parameters error on using parsed variable

Tags: android, android-volley

//Code

```
private void searchQuery(String strQuery, String link){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You searched for "+strQuery, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, link, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jresponse) {
                //displayResultInList(jresponse);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parameters.put("query", strQuery);
                return parameters;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        rQueue.add(request);

    }
```

This particular line:  parameters.put("query", strQuery); is giving an error and the error message says:
Variable 'strQuery' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.
I did some research and read some tutorials on POST requests using Volley and the large chunk of them are not using variables but strings in that function.The problem with setting the variable as final is that the user is typing it in therefore that variable will only have a value after the query is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the parameter variable in a block of code inside the method.

The JAVA compiler demands that the variables from **outside** the scope of the `Response.Listener` block are declared as final to guarantee that the variable value keeps the same (when the block is declared) when running the code.

It assures that you cannot modify the value of the variable after declaring the block.

So, you DO NEED to put `final` before `String strQuery` in the function parameter, since you're using it inside the block.